# odata V4 end point in ExplicitEDM

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I want to convert my odata service from version 3 to version 4.
I ran all the updates but when I do request I still get Version 3 instead of version 4.

I try to change my controller to inherit from ODataController and I put [EnableQuery] on the query but it didn't help.

My current EndPoint

```
        config.Routes.MapODataRoute("SituatorWebAPI", "odata",
            GetExplicitEDM(), new CountODataPathHandler(), 
            routingConventions,
            new ODataActionBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
```

And I start to build my model like this:

```
    private static IEdmModel GetExplicitEDM()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Starting to build EDM");

        var helper = new ModelBuilderHelper();

        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataModelBuilder();

        .
        .
        .
```

What should I change?

Comment: You should also pay attention to the namespace you're using. For WebAPI OData V3, it is System.Web.Http.OData. For V4, it is System.Web.OData. So at least you should get rid of the former namespace when you're to use V4.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog about start from WebAPI Odata V4: 
[Getting started with ASP.NET Web API 2.2 for OData v4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0.aspx)

To upgrade your service from V3 to V4, you may need the following step:

1. uninstall the V3 nuget package[Web API OData V3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/).
2. install V4 nuget package[Web API OData V4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/).
3. Change the related reference namespace in your service source code.
4. Update the service code (some method name may be changed)